# How to process elements only if they're _not_ followed by a specific element

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XML like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <mtef>
    <slot>
      <options>0</options>
      <char>
        <typeface>2</typeface>
        <mt_code_value>0x0028</mt_code_value>
      </char>
      <char>
        <typeface>3</typeface>
        <mt_code_value>0x0062</mt_code_value>
      </char>
      <char>
        <typeface>2</typeface>
        <mt_code_value>0x0029</mt_code_value>
      </char>
      <tmpl>
        <selector>tmSUP</selector>
        <template_specific_options>0</template_specific_options>
        <sub/>
        <slot>
          <options>1</options>
        </slot>
        <slot>
          <options>0</options>
          <char>
            <typeface>3</typeface>
            <mt_code_value>0x0063</mt_code_value>
          </char>
          <end/>
        </slot>
        <end/>
      </tmpl>
      <end/>
    </slot>
    <end/>
  </mtef>
</root>
```

If the `tmpl` element with the `tmSUP` selector is preceded by a `char` with a `mt_code_value` of 0x0029 (HTML entity for right parenthesis), then the processing of this `tmpl` element must find the opening, left parenthesis, and use those in-between `char` elements in its template.

The issue I'm having is with the double processing of `char` elements, first by their own template, then by the `tmpl[selector='tmSUP']` template. How do I prevent `char` elements from being processed when a succeeding `tmpl` element is following a `char` with the `mt_code_value` of 0x0029?

My stylesheet looks like this currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
           <xsl:apply-templates select=".//mtef" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mtef">
        <math>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot"/>
        </math>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="slot">
        <mrow>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </mrow>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tmpl[selector = 'tmSUP']">
        <msup>
        <mrow>
            <xsl:choose>
                <!-- Closing bracket -->
                <xsl:when test="preceding-sibling::char[1]/mt_code_value = '0x0029'">
                    <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*">
                        <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>            
        </mrow>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot[2]"/>
        </msup>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '2']">
        <mn>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mn>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '3']">
        <mi>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mi>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which results in this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <math>
    <mrow>  
      <mn>&#x0028;</mn>
      <mi>&#x0061;</mi>
      <mo>&#x2212;</mo>
      <mi>&#x0062;</mi>
      <mn>&#x0029;</mn>
      <msup>
        <mrow>
          <mn>&#x0028;</mn><mi>&#x0061;</mi><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mi>&#x0062;</mi><mn>&#x0029;</mn>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>  
          <mi>&#x0063;</mi>
        </mrow>
      </msup>
    </mrow>
  </math>
</root>
```

Notice how some elements appear twice.

The desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><root>
  <math>
    <mrow>  
      <msup>
        <mrow>
          <mn>&#x0028;</mn><mi>&#x0061;</mi><mo>&#x2212;</mo><mi>&#x0062;</mi><mn>&#x0029;</mn>
        </mrow>
        <mrow>  
          <mi>&#x0063;</mi>
        </mrow>
      </msup>
    </mrow>
  </math>
</root>
```

What is a general approach to solving this kind of conditional "look-ahead" processing with XSLT?

Comment: what's the expected output *exactly*?

Comment: Updated the question with the desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to move the condition on the `tmpl` out of the template that matches `tmpl` itself, and into the template that matches `slot`. That way, if the condition is true, you can select only the `tmpl` element then, and not the other `char` elements.

Therefore your template that matches `slot` would look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="slot">
    <mrow>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="tmpl[selector = 'tmSUP'][preceding-sibling::char[1]/mt_code_value = '0x0029']">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="tmpl" mode="sup" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </mrow>
</xsl:template>
```

The use of `mode` on the `xsl:apply-templates` is simply because you might have a separate template for `tmpl` that you want to use when the conditions are met.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
           <xsl:apply-templates select=".//mtef" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mtef">
        <math>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot"/>
        </math>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="slot">
        <mrow>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="tmpl[selector = 'tmSUP'][preceding-sibling::char[1]/mt_code_value = '0x0029']">
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="tmpl" mode="sup" />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </mrow>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tmpl" mode="sup">
        <msup>
            <mrow>
                <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>        
            </mrow>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot[2]"/>
        </msup>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '2']">
        <mn>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mn>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '3']">
        <mi>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mi>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am not sure if this gives you exactly the output you need, but it might be a start.

A slightly different approach, as you are using XSLT 2.0, is to use `xsl:for-each-group` and group ending with `tmpl`. You can then test if the last element in the group matches the condition, and act accordingly.

Try this XSLT too

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
           <xsl:apply-templates select=".//mtef" />
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="mtef">
        <math>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot"/>
        </math>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="slot">
        <mrow>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-ending-with="tmpl">
                <xsl:variable name="last" select="current-group()[last()]" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$last[self::tmpl][selector = 'tmSUP'][preceding-sibling::char[1]/mt_code_value = '0x0029']">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="$last" mode="sup" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </mrow>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tmpl" mode="sup">
        <msup>
            <mrow>
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group() except tmpl">
                    <xsl:sort select="position()" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>        
            </mrow>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="slot[2]"/>
        </msup>
     </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '2']">
        <mn>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mn>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="char[typeface = '3']">
        <mi>
            <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&amp;#</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring(mt_code_value/text(), 2)"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
        </mi>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Both of your approaches solve the described problem and have set me out on a good path to generally solve this issue (with several sibling `tmpl[selector='tmSUP']` elements and similar edge cases), so I will accept your answer. Thanks!